# How to get Python to work with Lighttpd?

Tags: python, web-server, lighttpd

I've got Lighttpd setup on my Raspberry Pi, but I'd like to get server-side code working now. I'm familiar with PHP, but I figure I should try Python as it's supposed to be the "go to" language for the Raspberry Pi. How can I get Python handling server-side code via Lighttpd?

Comment: http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/cgi/ link is broken but thanks for the great writeup. My Pi arrives tomorrow!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need is CGI support for lighttpd.

Open the lighttpd configuration file (**/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf**) and uncomment the "mod_cgi" line (remove the # from the beginning of the line if one exists) or add this line if not present.

```
server.modules = (
            "mod_access",
            "mod_alias",
            "mod_accesslog",
            "mod_auth",
            "mod_ssi",
            "mod_cgi",
            "mod_compress",
            "mod_fastcgi",
            "mod_rewrite",
            "mod_magnet",
)
```

Add the following to the bottom of the file:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
        cgi.assign = ( ".py" => "/usr/bin/python" )
}
```

Restart the lighttpd daemon:

```
sudo service lighttpd force-reload
```

Then create a **cgi-bin** directory under your webserver's root directory. Any files ending with .py in this directory will be processed by Python.

You can now write Python scripts to handle web requests. You may want to read this tutorial on [writing CGI programs with Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20120414121016/http://penzilla.net/tutorials/python/cgi/).

If on the other hand you would rather use a framework to handle some of the low level details and improve developer productivity, I suggest checking out [web.py](http://webpy.org/). You can install it using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python-webpy
```

Lucas at the Cloud 101 Blog has posted a great [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140225012136/http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/04/24/python-for-the-web-with-webpy) on writing web pages using the webpy framework.

Comment: Is this FastCGI or CGI?

Comment: Note that plain CGI requires starting the python interpreter for every request so it is only well suited for the occasional request.

Comment: Alas this only worked partially. I can now run python by calling "http://(IP)/cgi-bin/test.py?parameter=xxx" but not "http://(IP)/cgi-bin/test.cgi?parameter=xxx" - the later gives a 404 error...

Comment: @576i Try changing this line cgi.assign = ( ".py" => "/usr/bin/python" ) to cgi.assign = ( ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/python" )

Comment: @Steve. Alas this does not work. I still get the 404 error, but now  "http://(IP)/cgi-bin/test.py?parameter=xxx" will just offer me to download the file.

Comment: @576i Rather than continue this discussion in the comments of another question, Please open a new question and include what works and what you have tried. I will then delete these comments. BTW any reason why you can't just go with the .py extension, which you said works?

Comment: 404 is returned when the alias definition is missing. Please see my post below.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me and it also ignores the pre-configured packages that are available for Lighttpd.

**The correct way to install Python on Lighttpd for the Raspberry is:**

First enable cgi by

`sudo lighttpd-enable-mod cgi`

This creates a new configuration file for Lighttpd:

`/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-cgi.conf`

Edit the configuration file `nano /etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-cgi.conf`, to look similar to this

```
server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
        alias.url += ( "/cgi-bin/" => "/var/www/cgi-bin" )
        cgi.assign = (
                ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python",
        )
}
```

Make sure python 2 is installed by executing:

`/usr/bin/python --version`

Now, restart

`sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd force-reload`

Good luck!