# "404 not found" error when requesting Python with Lighttpd through CGI

Tags: python, lighttpd

I've installed lighttpd and gotten it to serve `/var/www/index.html` just fine, but I haven't gotten it to run a Python script yet.

I enabled CGI and set it's match case and directory as instructed in [this SO answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/how-to-get-python-to-work-with-lighttpd).  In short, I added `mod_cgi` to `server.modules()` and gave it a regex rule

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
    cgi.assign = ( ".py" => "/usr/bin/python" )
}
```

For my test file `/var/www/cgi-bin/test.py`:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"     
print ""                              
print "<body>"
print "TEST"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

When I enter the url `raspberrypi.local` or my IP, I get the file `/var/www/index.html` as expected.  When I request the url `raspberrypi.local/cgi-bin/test.py` or `raspberrypi.local/test.py` I get a 404 error.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:  I've also found [this tutorial](https://mike632t.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/installing-lighttpd-with-python-cgi-support/) which is very good, and says pretty much the same thing.  I'm still getting the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps:

First enable cgi by

`sudo lighttpd-enable-mod cgi`

This creates a new configuration file for Lighttpd:

`/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-cgi.conf`

Edit the configuration file `nano /etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-cgi.conf`, to look similar to this

```
server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
        alias.url += ( "/cgi-bin/" => "/var/www/cgi-bin" )
        cgi.assign = (
                ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python",
        )
}
```

Make sure python 2 is installed by executing:

`/usr/bin/python --version`

Now, restart

`sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd force-reload`

Good luck!

Comment: This just almost got it working: the alias should refer to `"/var/www/cgi-bin/"`, with a slash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps 2 years later, if you enabled it via lighty-mod-enable, or perhaps this is a version specific thing ( Using lighttpd 1.4.55 ), the link that is created in `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/` from the sample file at `/etc/lighttpd/conf-available` that is `10-cgi.conf`, contains

> alias.url += ( "/cgi-bin/" => "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/" )

Which aliases the /cgi-bin folder to the one in /usr/lib, which it took me a good minute to figure out after reading this post.

Regardless, you can remove this line if you do want to use the cgi-bin in /var/www/html/.../cgi-bin, or put your files at /usr/lib/cgi-bin

Hope that helps!